# Ruby Mechanize referencing pop up/new window

Tags: ruby, mechanize-ruby

I'm using Ruby with mechanize gem to try to scrape data from a website.  my question is, after login on the referenced page, the website launches a new page where the actual data lives.  How to I reference that new page in mechanize?

script so far:

```
require 'mechanize'

a = Mechanize.new
page = a.get('http://www.obfuscation.com')
formd = page.forms[0]

formd.txtUserName = 'username'
formd.txtPassword = 'password'
formd.submit
```

This is where I lose track programatically of the new spawned browser window.

your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Be advised that mechanize is not meant to interact with JavaScript. You may want to look into Watir which acts like a full fledged browser.

Comment: Thanks, just looked at it.  seems like it will work.  odd thing is it actually opens a browser, i'd prefer to not see it but oh well